# How do you upload a file to Firebase Storage using Python Flask?

Tags: python, firebase, file-upload, flask, firebase-storage

I want to upload a file, but the examples I've seen on stackoverflow were based on using `blobl.upload_from_string` which didn't match my use case of using an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the file object from Flask's `request.files` and send use that with `blob.upload_from_file` to upload binary files.

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

def uploadPhoto(userIDStr, file):
    path = '/bucketname/'+str(secure_filename(file.filename))
    if file: 
        try:
            bucket = storage.bucket()
            #file is just an object from request.files e.g. file = request.files['myFile']
            blob = bucket.blob(file.filename)
            blob.upload_from_file(file)
        except Exception as e:
            console.log('error uploading user photo: ' % e)
```

Relevant docs is under Blob's page: http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file

When using python libraries that don't have the most thorough use case examples, you can explore objects using `IPython` and pressing `TAB` after an `objectname.` to see its methods and members.